# std::string operator+() memory leak?

Tags: c++, string, stl, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm quite worry because I wrote a little application and it seems that there is a memory leak if I believe valgrind (What I actually do):

```
==9321== 251 bytes in 7 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==9321==    at 0x402569A: operator new(unsigned int) (vg_replace_malloc.c:255)
==9321==    by 0x40D3D05: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==9321==    by 0x40D4977: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==9321==    by 0x40D57AC: std::string::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==9321==    by 0x40D5EE6: std::string::operator+=(char) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.13)
==9321==    by 0x804E113: xl2::TextParser::getNextLfLine() (TextParser.cpp:162)
==9321==    by 0x804BFD5: xl2::UsbTree::parseStringInfo(xl2::TextParser&, std::string&, std::string&) (UsbTree.cpp:362)
==9321==    by 0x804B881: xl2::UsbTree::parseDevicesFile(std::string) (UsbTree.cpp:204)
==9321==    by 0x804B34E: xl2::UsbTree::updateTree() (UsbTree.cpp:70)
==9321==    by 0x804E2E4: scan(std::string) (testUsbTree.cpp:75)
==9321==    by 0x804E6CC: executeCommand(std::string) (testUsbTree.cpp:132)
==9321==    by 0x804E8F6: hushLoop() (testUsbTree.cpp:153)
```

Here is the function in question :

```
/**
 * Returns the next line separated by UNIX style LF
 * @return The next line separated by UNIX style LF
 */
std::string TextParser::getNextLfLine()
{
    std::string line;   // The builded line

    while(this->hasMoreToken())
    {
        line += this->m_pText[this->m_iTokenLocation++];

        // Check if we have just seen a CR/LF character
        if(this->m_pText[this->m_iTokenLocation - 1] == '\n')
            return line;
    }

    return line;
}
```

The programm terminates correctly by leaving the main funciton (no call to exit()).

I just don't understand why there is a memory leak. As my string is copied in the stack and the original string is supposed to be cleaned when the function is left, right? Or the error could be higher? At top level I also assign the returned value to a local variable that is then put as field into an object (by copy) ...

So I was wondering if the leak comes from the standard library or valgrind what would be really surprising!

Any pointers to not leaked memory is strongly appreciated :-p!

Comment: Actually I had a memory leak because I forgot to declare a destructor of a base class virtual, then running valgrind showed me a perfect memory leakless application! Morality: Get worry anyway for STL memory leak unless you really know what you are doing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To quote [Valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.reports)

> With GCC 2.91, 2.95, 3.0 and 3.1, compile all source using the STL with -D__USE_MALLOC. Beware! This was removed from GCC starting with version 3.3.
>
> With GCC 3.2.2 and later, you should export the environment variable GLIBCPP_FORCE_NEW before running your program.
>
> With GCC 3.4 and later, that variable has changed name to GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW.

Also discussed in [GCC FAQ](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/debug.html#debug.memory)

Comment: Did that answer actually fix the problem? It would surprise me. I haven't had to do those tricks since GCC 4.1 , I think.

Answer (score 8):

I would not worry too much about STL leaks.

The default STL allocator (for gcc) uses clever tricks to maximize efficiency that Valgrind often reports as leaks. Notably it pools memory, meaning that it keeps memory around when you clear a `string` and may reuse it next time you insert in a `map` or a `vector` for example.

I don't think the pool itself is properly disposed of at the end of the program, probably to avoid the Static Destruction Order Fiasco (ie, imagine that the pool is disposed of and you then request memory, urk). Thus it leaks... right before your program ends and the OS gets the memory back forcefully.

Comment: Of course no reasonable destructor will ever allocate memory (or do anything else that might throw), so it *should* be OK to free it, but apparently they've decided to tolerate this abuse.

Comment: @spraff: would you find it so strange to log during the shut-down ?

Comment: Allocating memory isn't necessarily capable of throwing, you could use nothrow new. Or just catch the exception before it leaves the destructor. Anyway, a standard library implementation isn't allowed to crash just because you do something unreasonable, when the unreasonable thing has defined behavior according to the standard. A third-party library could say, "if your global destructors allocate memory, things go boom", but the standard library can't.

Comment: @Matthieu it's possible to write logs without allocating memory

Comment: @Steve sure we could use non-throwing malloc and then it becomes reasonable. Also, the standard *language* doesn't *fully* support throwing destructors (during exceptions), so the library doesn't have to support them or state otherwise.

Comment: P.S. a throwing destructor means "this object has failed to cease to exist" -- IMHO it should be undefined behaviour.

Comment: You don't seem to be distinguishing between throwing an exception while in a destructor, vs throwing an exception out of a destructor. The language fully supports the former, there's no need to avoid it as long as the exception doesn't leave the destructor. It's not abuse. Even if it does leave, behavior is completely defined (if it occurs as part of stack unwinding then `terminate` is called, otherwise it behaves like any other exception). Granted that behavior isn't very useful, but there's no option for the standard library to cause anything else to happen.

Comment: @spraff: it is, but why go to all the trouble when I can format with streams as long as the Standard got a provision for it ? :) C++ is hard enough already :/ Note: with modules, we could avoid the issue !

Comment: @Steve I'm not disagreeing with you about what *is* only what *should be*, I don't believe the language should support throwing destructors under any circumstances -- I don't believe it should compile. `std::terminate` is a pisspoor cop-out the existence of which strongly suggests a big mistake has been made

Comment: @spraff: I *do* disagree with you. If deallocating memory fails, for example, then you'd better terminate as soon as possible. Whether by throwing or terminating does not matter. I would support a motion, though, that throwing from a destructor should simply call `terminate`, whether another exception is active or not.

Comment: @spraff: but what you originally said has nothing to do with throwing destructors. The thing you called "an abuse" was "allocating memory or doing anything else that might throw" in a destructor. Just because you call something that might throw does not mean that you throw, because you can catch the exception. So there was never any abuse. Whatever your dispute with the standard is, making it work your way would not allow STL implementations to ignore that a global destructor might allocate memory (and hence the pool can't be disposed of if there's risk of fiasco).

Comment: The default `std::allocator` for GCC does **not** pool anything. The default uses `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator` which as the name suggests just uses `new` and `delete`

Comment: @JonathanWakely: and yet we can routinely observe memory leaks report on `std::string` that seem to suggest such pooling, could it be an issue of `new` (or `malloc`) implementation that does such pooling ?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what's happening is the compiler is using NRVO to put your temporary string into its real return location. That return string is then stored inside an object that's allocated and leaked off the heap.