# Can I safely ignore any valgrind errors coming from std::string?

Tags: c++, stl, valgrind

I am working on a library (library A) that utilizes another library (library B) for string processing. I have set up library A with a series of unit tests, and before I push changes I like to run valgrind on each of these unit tests to make sure that my library is memory-safe, at least to the best of my knowledge.

However, recently I have been getting errors from a unit test of library A that are coming from library B. This is the error in question:

```
==9439== 73 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==9439==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9439==    by 0x5511B8A: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_mutate(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==9439==    by 0x5513132: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==9439==    by 0x4ED78D8: std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) (basic_string.h:5929)
==9439==    by 0x51B6DDB: PTL::PTLStaticBooleanArray::PTLStaticBooleanArray(int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double (*)(int)) (PTLStaticBooleanArray.cpp:43)
==9439==    by 0x10B8D8: cmf::CartesianMeshInputInfo::Define(PTL::PropertySection&) (CartesianMesh.h:87)
==9439==    by 0x10B618: cmf::CartesianMeshInputInfo::CartesianMeshInputInfo(PTL::PropertySection&) (CartesianMesh.h:76)
==9439==    by 0x10AC0B: main (simpletest.cc:10)
```

I have been playing around with library B for days to fix this error, but with no luck. I am aware of answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284344/stdstring-operator-memory-leak) which suggest that the complexity of the memory management inside the STL seems to trick valgrind into reporting it as a memory leak.

The problematic code in library B is the following constructor:

```
PTLStaticBooleanArray::PTLStaticBooleanArray(int assertCount_in, std::string descriptionIn)
    {
        strHandle = new PropStringHandler();
        this->SetDescription(descriptionIn);
        defaultValue = "[]";
        std::string fstr = GetBoolStr(false);
        if (assertCount_in>0)
        {
            defaultValue = "[" + fstr;
            for (int i = 1; i < assertCount_in; i++)
            {
                defaultValue += ","+fstr; // this is identified as the problematic call to _M_mutate
            }
            defaultValue += "]";
        }
        basePointerType = BasePointer::BooleanArrayPointer;
        requiresDelete = false;
        basePtr = NULL;
        count = 0;
        assertCount = assertCount_in;
        basePtr = new bool[assertCount_in];
        requiresDelete = true;
        hasFiller = false;
    }
```

What makes me slightly uncomfortable ignoring this error is that I can change only the values of the string returned by the `GetBoolStr()` function and the error vanishes. I can also make the error vanish by instantiating the troublesome class outside of the internals of library B. This kind of behavior suggests to me that something is actually wrong with library B.

I also realize that I can generate a suppression file that valgrind can use when running my unit tests for library A, but this is not something I am interested in as this would introduce a lot of manual labor moving forward.

In summary, can I conclude that this issue is just "STL tricking valgrind" whenever I see the issue coming from an STL function, or should I pour more resources into finding the root cause if I want my code to be memory safe?

Comment: Have you tried recompiling with `GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW=1`? That should disable the pool allocation. Anyway, the pragmatic answer is if it's just one block overall, that will not create problems even if it is a real leak. If it loses one block at each call, that would be worth going after. Try calling the constructor a few more (thousand) times...

Comment: @dratenik I have not tried that, but I will give it a shot. Indeed, the troublesome constructor is only called one time in any application that uses the library, so I don't think I will need to sweat it.